# Getting a player's Mouse.hit from server

Tags: lua, game-development, roblox

I have a question regarding Roblox and the player's Mouse.hit position.

So i am developing a gun, that needs the player's Mouse Hit Position to shoot to the needed destination.
Now i know that hackers can edit localscripts and maybe change the end position from the Mouse.hit to a specific player making Aimbots easy to make.
I need a way to give the server the client's Mouse.hit without an exploiter begin able to modify it.

I have tried already getting the Mouse.hit from the server

```
event.OnServerEvent:connect(function(player)
 local MousePos = player:GetMouse().Hit.Position
end)
```

but that didn't work as i realized that the mouse only exists in the client.
Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution would be to send over the mouse data from the client to the server, one of the options is to use [Remote Events](https://create.roblox.com/docs/scripting/events/remote#remote-events).
Since you main objective is to deter exploiters, the most you can do is rely on Roblox' new anti-cheat, Vanguard, and add some server-side sanity checks on the mouse (e.g. ray reconstruction or something less expensive)